# reload data in TableView after inserting data through web service

Tags: objective-c, ios7

[image]

I am using JSON parsing to upload data in `UITableView`. Everything is working fine but after inserting data through textView it's uploading on server but it's not refreshing in my previous and current `UITableView`. I need to restart my project to see the uploaded data. I want to reload my `UITableView` after inserting data. I used `[self.myTableView reloadData]` but it's not working anywhere.

```
-(PrayerListCustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    PrayerListCustomCell *cell = (PrayerListCustomCell *)[tableView 
           dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"PrayerListCustomCell" 
        owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
 }

  cell.dateLbl.text = [dateList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.prayerLbl.text = [prayerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
 -(void)submitClicked
{
if ([prayerTextView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please fill 
     your request in text box!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  
     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
    prayerSubmitData = prayerTextView.text;
    SubmitPrayer *submit = [[SubmitPrayer alloc]init];
    [ASKevrOperationManager submitPrayer:submit handler:^(id object , NSError *error 
       , BOOL success)
     {
         if (success) {
             NSLog(@"this is request data = %@",object);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
              message:@"Successful upload!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
              otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             prayerTextView.text = @"";
             [self.requestTableView reloadData];
            //Do refreshment code
         }
         else
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
            message:@"Please try again later!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
             otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
         }
     } ];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you also updating your model?

Comment: It would help if we could see some code

Comment: have you tried to `setNeedDisplay` after `reloadData` ?

Comment: Can you add code sample here to find your problem..

Comment: Hey @Chaaruu reload your json and table reload after refill your array.,

Comment: @BhaveshNai Can you please give me any example..Because i have created common JSON parsing and calling only URLs from different file.

Comment: in this code I can't see where do you change the table datasource , you cannot update table without changing its datasource ... however if you want to update textview then just use `[self.prayerTextView setNeedDisplay];

Comment: if you do change the table's datasource in some other part of your code so -> you should reload table there after performing those changes.

Comment: reload your array data before reloading table

Comment: Plz put some code for getting list.,

Comment: @BhaveshNai Please check it now..

Comment: @Flexicoder I put code and my view controller screen shot..Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your committed data into your `prayerList` array. This should be something like this:

```
if (success) {
   // show alert

   [prayerList addObject:prayerTextView.text];
   [self.requestTableView reloadData];
   prayerTextView.text = @"";

   //Do refreshment code
}
```

Comment: I tried for this but it's crashing because i am calling data from server which is having prayer with date&time.I have only one solution if i follow you.the solution is I need to pass date&time too with data then only i can update date&time otherwise i need to call this web service again to refresh table data..Is there other solution you have?

Comment: Why don't you also add your date-object to the `dateList` array?

edit: Ah I see you get the Date from the web service only and don't have it locally. So you either need to retrieve your data from the server again and THEN reload the tableView OR you need to generate the date locally and add it to your dateList-array.